# How to implement acrylic windows effect in WinUI3 in desktop application?

Tags: uwp, .net-6.0, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3, winui

When creating WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK 1.0) project with VS 2022, I am unable to implement the acrylic background effect on Windows. I have done a lot of research and seen samples but unfortunately could not find reliable resources to implement Acrylic in WinUI 3 in Desktop. Please note I am specifically talking about 'WinUI 3 in Desktop' App not WinUI2 and UWP.

Not including any code because I have not implemented anything specific. Just created the template provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you check out the WinUI Controls Library app in Microsoft Store? If has some examples how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, **WinUI** 3 in Desktop Apps does not support Acrylic or Mica materials as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md).
The support will come in Windows App SDK 1.1 probably in 2nd Quarter of 2022.

Answer (score 3):

Acrylic effect is finally available in the app starting with Windows App SDK version 1.1 with 2 classes:

- [DesktopAcrylicController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.composition.systembackdrops.desktopacryliccontroller?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1), which uses whatever is below the window to create the backdrop.
- [MicaController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.composition.systembackdrops.micacontroller?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1), which uses the user's wallpaper to create the backdrop.

Take a look at
[sample for winrt/cpp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller).

Note that for C#, the sample is available in the WinUI3 Gallery (System backdrop).

Comment: But not working on Windows 10 for some reason...